# Blockquote tags are not visible when looking at your own answers, though the preview shows them

Tags: support, markdown-preview, blockquote

A while back, I posted this question: [Get Dingbats to appear in Firefox 3?](https://superuser.com/questions/14087/get-dingbats-to-appear-in-firefox-3)

Today, I revisited it to add an answer sourced from [Check marks indicating obtained badges use unicode &#10004 symbol, not available for many users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1861/check-marks-indicating-obtained-badges-use-unicode-10004-symbol-not-available/1879#1879)

Since I'd sourced it from someone else, I of course attributed the quote in a <blockquote> tag.

This is how it appeared in the preview:
[Preview http://img300.imageshack.us/img300/900/previewa.gif](http://img300.imageshack.us/img300/900/previewa.gif)

This is how it appeared in the page:
[My block http://img30.imageshack.us/img30/9296/noblock.gif](http://img30.imageshack.us/img30/9296/noblock.gif)

It appears to just be *my* answer, because the other answer on the page has the blockquote (apparently) working fine:
[His block http://img38.imageshack.us/img38/6023/blockukv.gif](http://img38.imageshack.us/img38/6023/blockukv.gif)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well the actual markup is

```
<blockquote>This can be corrected (in IE at least) by going to
Tools > Internet Options > "General" tab > Fonts and select "Arial Unicode MS" 
as the default font.
</blockquotequote>
```

note the error in the markup. I'll fix the error.

Comment: I can now see the quote inline, as expected.  Apparently today was far longer than I'd thought.  :$.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using `<blockquote>` - does it work if you use the quote markdown?

> like this

(which is `> like this`)

> just testing blockquote

Answer (score 0):

```
> This is how you do a blockquote in Markdown
>
> `Tools > Internet Options > "General" tab > Fonts`
>
>- Lists work too!
>  1. sub-lists also work
```

> This is how you do a blockquote in Markdown
>
> `Tools > Internet Options > "General" tab > Fonts`
>
> - Lists work too!
>
>   1. sub-lists also work

Although I occasionally hand write the html, if I want to do something that doesn't quite work in Markdown.

For example code blocks that are embedded in block quotes.

```
<blockquote>
<p>
This is an example of a code block in a block quote:
<pre><code>if ( $a == $b ){
  return 'true'
}
</code></pre>
</p>
</blockquote>
```

> This is an example of a code block in a block quote:
>
> ```
> if ( $a == $b ){
>   return 'true'
> }
> ```